# How to customize .vcxproj file?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, msbuild, cl

So I am using **MSBuild** via command line, but I have few questions when customizing my **.vcxproj** file:

- how to use custom output instead of default one(x64/Debug and x64/Release, but I want bin/release and bin/debug)
- how to embed properties which I use on command line `MSBuild.exe make.vcxproj -property:Configuration=Debug -property:Platform=x64`

Comment: Have you read [.vcxproj and .props file structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/vcxproj-file-structure?view=msvc-160)  ?

Comment: did indeed, but couldnt find anything related or at least good explanation

Comment: Output directory = `OutDir` property, which you define in a `<PropertyGroup>` element;  Configuration and Platform go in a ProjectConfiguration ItemGroup, which is documented in the above link. To figure this out open a project in VS, change settings in the UI, then see how this gets reflected in the .vcxproj file.

Comment: helpful answer, thanks a lot